# amdgpu driver crashes

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, gpu, amd-graphics

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot these, but at least once a week, the amdgpu driver crashes and I either have to hard power down or try to ssh in from my laptop and reboot.

```
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XL/XT [Radeon RX Vega 56/64] (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Device e37f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 103
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at fcc00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Here's the last kernel log
https://pastebin.com/d6qyJ8ha

I'm on Fedora 31 running a vanilla kernel (I was hoping this slightly newer kernel would fair better). Details are at the top of the kernel log pastebin

Maybe I need to submit a bug report but I'm not even sure what information I need & if there's any troubleshooting I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little you can do to solve this issue on your own, so do please file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers (choose *Video(Other)* as a component).

What info you could provide (attach it as files):

- Full `sudo dmesg` output
- Full `sudo lspci -vvv` output
- Full `sudo lshw` output

And of course describe under which circumstances you get this issue.